# @babel/register support source maps on runtime

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-register

There is code that is transpiled by babel. But on runtime error it shows a wrong line number.

I run the script this way.

```
node -r ./runner.js ./index.js
```

It uses the runner.

```js
console.log('Runner. Registers babel.')

require('source-map-support').install()

require('@babel/register')({
  extensions: ['.js'],
  ignore: [
    /node_modules[\\/](?!console-command-manager)/
  ],
});
```

Babel register uses the config from babel.config.js

```js
console.log('Babel. Configuration.');

module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]],
  plugins: [],
  sourceMap: "inline"
};
```

When I throw an error in the code on runtime. It shows me wrong line numbers. I understand that source-map-support does not work.

VSCode debugging goes well. The editor see and understand source maps.

Help me to make source-maps workable.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin registration of [babel-plugin-source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-source-map-support) in babel.config.js is missed.
Read the description of the library [babel-plugin-source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-source-map-support)
There two libraries are needed: [babel-plugin-source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-source-map-support) and [source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support). Install them  both.

In babel file, register source-map-support plugin

```js
{
  sourceMaps: true,
  plugins: ['source-map-support', ...]
}
```

Enable on runtime in a file at the top.

```js
require('source-map-support').install()
```

Now, when it fails it has to show the right error line number of the source code.